# how to add dependecy in spark when using sbt to compile?

Tags: apache-spark, dependencies, sbt, apache-spark-mllib

when I look though the introduction in MLLIB part, I read the following  sentence:
      "To use native libraries from netlib-java, please build Spark with -Pnetlib-lgpl or include com.github.fommil.netlib:all:1.1.2 as a dependency of your project"
        Since I am a newer with sbt, so I really have no idea how to add dependency on it. Can someone give me some advise?
        In fact, I also do not know whether it matters if I just ignore the dependency
        Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your project sbt definition file add the line

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.fommil.netlib" % "all" % "1.1.2"
```

Check the below link

https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Basic-Configuration#by-example